# JQuery reveal div on click and hover of text link - a more elegant solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created the following script to reveal a text box on right when a navigation link is clicked on the left.

This code seems too basic and I'm thinking there's gotta be a more elegant way to code the javascript.

I have it set to add the class of "active" to a text link once it's been clicked (for styling purposes).

After adding 10 navigation links and corresponding text blocks, the javascript code gets really long. I'd also like this to work on-hover as well,  Why?  So on mobile devices they can click to reveal and on desktop only need to hover.

```js
$(function() {
   $('.rollover-3').click(function() {
       $('.rollover-text-3').show();
       $('.rollover-text-2').hide();
       $('.rollover-text-1').hide();
       return false;
   });
   $('.rollover-2').click(function() {
       $('.rollover-text-3').hide();
       $('.rollover-text-2').show();
       $('.rollover-text-1').hide();
       return false;
   });
   $('.rollover-1').click(function() {
       $('.rollover-text-3').hide();
       $('.rollover-text-2').hide();
       $('.rollover-text-1').show();
       return false;
   });
});
   
   
$(function() { 
  $(".rollover-3").click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.rollover-2').removeClass('active');
    $('.rollover-text-1').removeClass('active');
  });

  $(".rollover-2").click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.rollover-3').removeClass('active');
    $('.rollover-1').removeClass('active');
  });

  $(".rollover-1").click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.rollover-3').removeClass('active');
    $('.rollover-2').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.rollover-text-2, .rollover-text-3 {
   display: none;
}
.leftnav {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.right {    
    width:50%;
    float:right;
 }
 a.active {
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .rollover-text-1 {
     background-color: aqua;
 }
  .rollover-text-2 {
     background-color: yellow;
 }
  .rollover-text-3 {
     background-color: orange;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="leftnav">
    <p><a class="rollover-1 active" href="#">Link 1</a></p>
    <p><a class="rollover-2" href="#">Link 1</a></p>
    <p><a class="rollover-3" href="#">Link 1</a></p>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="rollover-text-1">Test 1 description here</div>
    <div class="rollover-text-2">Test 2 description here</div>
    <div class="rollover-text-3">Test 3 description here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
   $('.rollover').on('click mouseover', function() {
       $('.rollover-text').hide();
       $('.rollover').removeClass('active');
       $('.' + this.dataset.tab).show();
       $(this).addClass('active');
       return false;
   });
});
```

```css
.rollover-text-2, .rollover-text-3 {
   display: none;
}
.leftnav {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.right {    
    width:50%;
    float:right;
 }
 a.active {
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .rollover-text-1 {
     background-color: aqua;
 }
  .rollover-text-2 {
     background-color: yellow;
 }
  .rollover-text-3 {
     background-color: orange;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="leftnav">
    <p><a data-tab="rollover-text-1" class="rollover rollover-1 active" href="#">Link 1</a></p>
    <p><a data-tab="rollover-text-2" class="rollover rollover-2" href="#">Link 1</a></p>
    <p><a data-tab="rollover-text-3" class="rollover rollover-3" href="#">Link 1</a></p>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="rollover-text rollover-text-1">Test 1 description here</div>
    <div class="rollover-text rollover-text-2">Test 2 description here</div>
    <div class="rollover-text rollover-text-3">Test 3 description here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome!  I knew there had to be an easier way!   Works great!